# IIS7 Express missing 'IIS Manager Users' function

Tags: iis, iis-7

Using Windows 7 Home Premium with IIS 7.5 Express installed I cannot find the 'IIS Manage Users' function on the localhost / webserver level.

I have been in Control Panel --> Programs and Features --> Turn Windows Features On/Off --> and pretty much enabled/installed everything for IIS and it's security sub folder but no such functionality can be found within IIS after restarting it.

My final goal is to create an IIS Manager User Account (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732621(v=ws.10).aspx).

How to enable the 'IIS Manage Users' function within IIS 7.5 Express?

edit: I'm suspecting this is due to my Win7 version? Upgrading to Ultimate might do the trick:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753473.aspx
2nd edit: Upgrading to Win7 Ultimate DID NOT add this functionality.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this:
On the control Pane click on: "Uninstall a Program" => "Turn Windows features on or off".

Under Server Roles find "Web Server (IIS) => "Management Tools" "Management Service" and then click on install.

Then go to IIS Management and you will see on your machine or the sites some new options under "Management".

Comment: That's only available on Windows Server releases.